# Missing parameter type for expanded function while creating partially applied function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying

I am new to Scala and was reading about partially applied functions in Scala. I've a general function "wrap" which can concatenate three strings.

```
def wrap(prefix: String)(html: String)(suffix: String) = prefix + html + suffix
```

When I try to make a specialized function like this

```
val foo = wrap(_)("Hello")(_)
```

It fails with Missing parameter type error, but works if I provide type for first argument, like this

```
val foo = wrap(_:String)("Hello")(_)
```

My questions are:

1. Why do I have to provide the type redundantly? I had already provided it in general definition of wrap.
2. Why it doesn't require type for last argument?

Comment: 2) It does require type for last argument too, at least for me. Scala 2.12.7

Comment: Sometimes the inference engine just needs a hint or two: `val semiwrap :String => String => String = wrap(_)("Hello")`

Comment: @ygor .   I am also on 2.12.7. It works for me.                                                     scala> wrap("fd")("dfd")(_)
res0: String => String = $$Lambda$3062/0x0000000800f6b040@27c551c1

Answer (score 2):

As you have discovered, you need to give the compiler a bit more information about the types before it can work out the type of `foo`. You can either specify the argument types:

```
val foo = wrap(_: String)("Hello")(_: String)
```

or the result type

```
val foo: (String, String) => String = wrap(_)("Hello")(_)
```

Specifying a single type does not compile in my build using `2.12.7`

```
val foo = wrap(_: String)("Hello")(_) // Does not compile
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But do you know why compiler can't infer types because I've given it in my generic method wrap.

Answer (score 2):

Scala compiler cannot always infer types, for example: think of overloaded methods where it’s impossible for the compiler to know which of them you are referring to.

```
  def wrap(prefix: String)(html: String)(suffix: String) = prefix + html + suffix
  def wrap(prefix: Int)(html: String)(suffix: String) = prefix.toString + html + suffix

  val foo = wrap(_: String)("Hello")(_: String)
  val foo1 = wrap(_)("Hello")(_)     // compilation Error: Cannot resolve method 'wrap'
```

So, you need to explicitly specify type parameter like below:

```
  val foo = wrap(_: String)("Hello")(_: String)
  val foo1 = wrap(_: Int)("Hello")(_: String)
```

or specify return type explicitly:

```
  val foo: (String, String) => String = wrap(_)("Hello")(_)
  val foo1: (Int, String) => String = wrap(_)("Hello")(_)
```